# Apple Watch Notification Actions not working when iPhone companion app is terminated watch OS 5.3.2

Tags: ios, notifications, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch, notification-action

I am working on iOS app which is supported watch as well
below is my concerns.

watch os - 5.3.2 and iOS 13.1

I am facing problem with notification actions in watch app. when iPhone app is terminated and if I get a notification in watch , if I tap on action nothing happens.

I am relaying on push notification and for user notification actions I am registering for user notification.

as below

```
 // this I will call in iPhone app code in did finishlaunching with options.

   func registerForPushNotifications(withUserInfo userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]?) {
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            self.requestAuthorization(withUserInfo: userInfo)
        } else {
            registerUserNotificationSettings(withUserInfo: userInfo)
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
    }

  func registerUserNotificationSettings() {
        let approveAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        approveAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Approve", comment: "Notification approve button title")
        approveAction.identifier = "approve"
        approveAction.isDestructive = false
        approveAction.activationMode = .background
        approveAction.isAuthenticationRequired = true

        let denyAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
        denyAction.title = NSLocalizedString("Deny", comment: "Notification deny button title")
        denyAction.identifier = "deny"
        denyAction.isDestructive = true
        denyAction.activationMode = .background
        denyAction.isAuthenticationRequired = true

        let signInCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
        signInCategory.setActions([approveAction, denyAction], for: .default)
        signInCategory.identifier = "pushotp"

        let categories = NSSet(object: signInCategory) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>

        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.badge, .sound, .alert], categories: categories)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        })
    }
```

**Scenarios**

1. When iPhone app is in background and iPhone is locked and watch
   is in background. If I push a push notification from server , watch
   displays notification banner with two actions, if I tap any one
   action , its working fine.
2. when iPhone app is killed and iPhone locked immmediatly If I send
   pushnotification , watch displays notification banner with two
   actions, if I tap any one actions its working fine.
3. When iPhone app is killed and iPhone locked, kept both watch and
       iPhone idle for a hour so. then I will activate the watch and push
       the notification from server, now watch displays banner with two
       actions, now if I tap on the actions it is not working.

It would be great if you guys tell me what is the correct thing I have to do.

Comment: Could someone Help me on this

Comment: Could someone Help me on this

Answer (score 0):

To ensure that the actions are taken in the 3rd use case, please ensure that **Notification Payload** should have **contentAvailable** property to **YES**. So that the application will launch in background.
And it will update the notification user actions accordingly.